# How to replace 3 or more letters occurring together with doubles using java regex?

Tags: java, regex

How to replace 3 or more letters occurring together with doubles using java regex?
like oooooops with oops
and yesssssss with yess

Answer (score 6):

```
string.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1{2,}", "$1$1")
```

Comment: You might want `(\w)` instead of the `(.)`.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Yes, makes more sense I guess.

Comment: Languages without literal regex syntax (that you have to escape slashes in) make me sad

Comment: if Letter only and no number, underscore, its "\pL" or "\p{L}" or "\p{Letter}" (your choice ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Just as with every other language...

To match three or more, you can use `/.{3,}/`. To capture the same character, use a backreference `/(.)\1{2,}/`, and you can replace it easily with 2 occurences of the captured group. And to capture only letters, you might use non-whitespace characters `\S`:

```
str.replace("(\\S)\\1{2,}", "$1$1");
```

Comment: That won't match 3 *of the same letter* in a row

Comment: originalText = originalText.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1{2,}", "$1$1");this  works..thanx :) :)

Comment: But I want it to work on only letters (A-Za-z)?? What to do about that..?

Comment: i do not want 1000 dollars to become 100 dollars..isnt it? bcoz i m just trying to remove unwanted characters....

Comment: See @Mohammer s comment on Keppils answer. If you don't want to only match [a-zA-Z], use \pL (as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg))

Answer (score 0):

This is the working as your request:

[Regex Example](http://regexr.com?31h9e)